# How not to ask for publish permission everytime?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I did this in facebook

```
[self vSuspendAndHaltThisThreadTillUnsuspendedWhileDoing:^{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self.ACAstore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.ACAccounts options:[self dicPostOptions] completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            self.bPermissionToAccessStoreGranted=granted;
            [self vContinue];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Basically I am asking for publish permission. What I want to do is to check whether such publish permission has been granted or not before asking again.

How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

To check permissions available:

```
      if(![postRequest.session.permissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"])
```

Comment: what is postRequest? Starting from starting the new program here. I am using social framework. Not facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `FBRequest` with the open graph API with `me/permissions`. It will return you a response with a dictionary where the key are the permissions.

```
FBRequest *req = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" parameters:Nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[req startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
NSDictionary* result,
NSError *error) {
      BOOL canPublish = FALSE;
      if (!error)
      {
         FBGraphObject *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
         for(NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *aKey in data) 
         {
             canPublish = [[aKey objectForKey:@"publish_stream"] boolValue];
         }
      }
      else
      {
         NSLog(@"%@", error);
      }

      NSLog(@"%@", canPublish ? @"I have publish perms" : @"I don't have publish perms");
}];
```

Comment: But I am using social framework. What do I need to do if I use social framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

First of all implement all the facebook sdk delegate methods in your app delegate.

```
- (IBAction)loginWithFacebookButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    IntubeAppDelegate *delegat = (IntubeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegat doLoginAndSwitch];
}
```

Now, in your appDelegate -

```
-(void) doLoginAndSwitch
{      
    [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil]; 
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                         allowLoginUI:YES
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                        [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                            state:state
                                                            error:error];

                                    }];
}

-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowPublishStreamPermission:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream", nil];

[[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error){
}];
    return YES;
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
              state:(FBSessionState)state
              error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if(!error)
            {
                //  NSLog(@"FBSessionStateOpen :- logged in");

                [self openSessionWithAllowPublishStreamPermission:YES];

               // Your code
            }
     }    
}
```

I hope you would get what you desire now. :)